# Match an abbrevations like "ccd" , "bbq", "phd" etc to most similar string from a set of strings

Tags: algorithm, nlp, pattern-matching, dynamic-programming, string-matching

I have a list of abbrevations like "ccd" , "bbq", "phd" etc.

For example let's take "bbq" , we try to map this abbrevation to a list of strings,

Barbeque Nation - The actual answer should be this

BBQ Smoke and Grill

Beer and Bakes Gates

How do we decide to which string does the abbrevations belongs to. I have tried using string matching through KMP and Longest Common Subsequence algorithm with an added tweak of adding more value to to strings that are matched earlier.

Is there any data structure that can help or any algorithm that can deal with such cases?

Thanks!

Comment: Before you can do anything, you need a way of scoring how well an abbreviation matches a string; the problem then becomes one of determining which string has the highest score (in the worst case, you just calculate the score for each of them, and pick the highest).  There are various ways of scoring matches, but I can't think of any that would obviously score "Barbeque Nation" higher than "BBQ Smoke and Grill" -- and in any case, *you* have to decide which scoring function to use.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, coreference problem. My specialty.

One way to look at it is as a spelling correction problem to a dictionary. What you want is to have two components, an edit distance metric as noted by j_random_hacker AND a dictionary that lists all the accepted abbreviations. You might want to include a count in the dictionary so more common long forms count more.

The edit distance model is going to be determined by tuning against an evaluation metric. There is a good tutorial on spell checking at http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/querySpellChecker/read-me.html

You won't be using a language model to evaluate edits but it will set you up for performance metrics, edit distance etc...

Breck

Clarification for follow up question:

Your metrics will be driven by the performance of the system. You look at what the system got right, what it got wrong and you then modify edit distance to better model what you want.

So the score of the dictionary can be whether the phrase is in or out of the dictionary. I'd start with first character match with a score of -1 per word in phrase and -1 for skipped function words in phrase like 'and', -5 for skipping a letter in the acronym.  So  "bbq", by looking at the dictionary can be matched to "Beer and Bakes Gates"  with a score of -8 (-1+-1+-1+-5)

"Barbeque Nation" will need edits that score better. So letter in same word gets scores of -.5 and skipped word is -6.5 (-.5+-.5+-.5+-5) which is a better score. These edit costs have to be balanced over the training set you have which should be several thousand examples if you want any generality.

Comment: Hi Breck, can you please let me know what all metrics I can use to evaluate edits. What all I can understand is that I can reduce the number of strings being compared (i.e. the dictionary of acceptable full forms of abbreviations)  by checking if the characters of the abbrevations comes in the same order in the string.

Comment: Sorry for being so late in reply. Edits made in answer.

Comment: Thanks Breck, will think on these lines and see how the system performs.